# Why does this use of Generics not throw a runtime or compile time exception?

Tags: java, generics

I've got a method in a class that has a return type specified by use of a generic.

```
public class SomeMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
    System.out.println(foo.getFoo()); // Works, prints out "Foo"

  }

  public static class Foo<E>  {
    public E getFoo() {
      return (E) "Foo";
    }
  }
}
```

With the generic return type, I assumed the return in the above example would evaluate to:

```
return (Integer) "Foo";  // Inconvertible types !!!
```

Instead a `String` is returned and printed correctly.

I get a compilation error if I change the call to be:

```
String fooString = foo.getFoo(); // Compile error, incompatible types found
System.out.println(fooString);
```

What am I missing to help me understand what's going on here and why the original version didn't result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because overload resolution resolved your `println` call to `println(Object)`, since there is no `println(Integer)`.

Keep in mind that Java's generics are erased at runtime. And casts like `(E) "Foo"` are removed, and are moved to call site. Sometimes this is not necessary, so things are casted to the right type only when needed.

In other words, no casts are performed inside `getFoo`. The language spec supports this:

> Section 5.5.2  **Checked Casts and Unchecked Casts**
>
> - The cast is a completely unchecked cast.
>
>   No run-time action is performed for such a cast.

After erasure, `getFoo` returns `Object`. And that gets passed into `println(Object)`, which is perfectly fine.

If I call this method and pass `foo.getFoo`, I *will* get an error:

```
static void f(Integer i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
// ...
f(foo.getFoo()); // ClassCastException
```

because this time it *needs* to be casted.

Comment: Think that new rule should be introduced in `lint` that highlights generics usage with compile-time constants

Comment: Interesting.  So, the `E` in the method declaration `public E getFoo()` does nothing at run-time, only acts a compile time checking on uses of the signature, not what's going in inside the method.

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.println` does not have an overload that takes `Integer`. So this statement:

```
System.out.println(foo.getFoo());
```

Is calling `System.out.println(Object);`.

To verify that it would otherwise fail, try:

```
Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
Integer fooInt = foo.getFoo(); //class cast exception
```

The following will fail in the same way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
    print(foo.getFoo()); //Would also fail with a class cast exception
}
static void print(Integer in) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

And this is failing compilation for obvious reasons:

```
String fooString = foo.getFoo(); //can't work
```

`foo` is `Foo<Integer>`, and `foo.getFoo()` returns an `Integer` and the compiler can pick this up.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that during the [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) process, the Java compiler replaces the unbounded type parameter `E` with `Object`, therefore the `Foo` class is actually compiled into:

```
public static class Foo {
    public Object getFoo() {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

That's why the following code is valid (cast is not needed):

```
Object obj = foo.getFoo();
System.out.println(obj);
```

At the same time, the next code snippet produces a compile-time error, as expected:

```
Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();
String fooString = foo.getFoo(); // you're trying to trick the compiler (unsuccessfully)
           ^
incompatible types: Integer can not be converted to String
```

And that's the main responsibility of *generics* - compile-time checks.

Yet there is another side of the story - execution-time casts. For example, if you write:

```
Integer value = foo.getFoo();
```

you get a `ClassCastException` thrown at runtime (the Java compiler inserts a `checkcast` instruction that examines whether the result of the `foo.getFoo()` can be cast to `Integer`).